# Writing a function using switch case statement beginner javascript

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

```
function hardTotals(dealersCard, myTotal){
switch(dealersCard, myTotal){

case 7 || 8 || 9 || 10 || "A", 16 || 15 || 14:
    return "Hit";
    break;
   }
}
var text = hardTotals(9, 14);
console.log(text);\'''
```

I am trying to build a basic blackjack card counter. I am using switch case statements to tell the program what to do following basic strategy charts. This is a piece of my function hard Totals where I am trying to say if these cards are the dealers Card and these cards are my Total return hit. This is returning undefined. I am not sure why. I am very new to JS so any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please add some use cases for the wanted results.

Comment: switch only takes one argument?  Also usually when you want one thing to happen for multiple cases, you just let the cases fall through to a single one before breaking

Comment: Yeah, `case "A", 16:` doesn't make sense

Comment: I am still confused? If you plug in text = hardTotals("A", 16); it returns Hit. If you plug in 9, 14 for some reason it returns undefined.

Comment: Use cases are to use a basic strategy chart for blackjack and implement a function that I can put a function(param1, param2) into and it tells me what action to do based on the 2 numbers. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to link to an external site but this is the chart I'm referring to : https://www.blackjackapprenticeship.com/blackjack-strategy-charts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hardTotals(dealersCard, myTotal){
switch(dealersCard, myTotal){

case 7 || 8 || 9 || 10 || "A", 16 || 15 || 14: //problem
    return "Hit";
    break;
   }
}
var text = hardTotals(9, 14);
console.log(text);
```

Hey guys, found the solution. For some reason switch statement will accept 2 arguments but will only accept 1 argument possibility for the second argument.
So looks like because 14 was the third option for the second argument it returned undefined. This would be the same output using 15. 16 works for all of the param1 arguments though. Thanks all. Would love advice if anyone has it about a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Comma operator. This looks like a numeric comparison, not a switch, where ace can be either 1or 11, but that will require another conditional.